# retrieve firebird users passwords

Tags: delphi, firebird

My application currently is using the firebird security to logon for any user of my application.

We are using Delphi7 and Firebird 2.1.

Now we need to change this and we need to control de access by ourself.

We are thinking about retrieve all users passwords from the database (as a conversion routine) and save the password inside our tables....

Is possible to do this?

I'm trying to use the delphi component TIBSecurityService, but without success.

Take a look:

```
var
  i: integer;
  l: TStrings;
  pwd: string;
begin
  IBSecurityService1.Attach;
  IBSecurityService1.DisplayUsers;
  l := TStringList.Create;
  try
    for i := 0 to IBSecurityService1.UserInfoCount-1 do
      l.add(IBSecurityService1.UserInfo[i].UserName);

    while l.Count > 0 do
      try
        IBSecurityService1.DisplayUser(l[0]);
        pwd := IBSecurityService1.Password;
        // pwd = ''
      finally
        l.Delete(0);
      end;
  finally
    l.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: I really hope that this is not possible!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Passwords in Firebird are hashed, so you cannot recover them.

Comment: Here can I found the algorithm to hash a password, as so I can save the encrypted password from inside security2.fdb

Comment: You can save the hashed version of the password, but you will not be able to reverse the hash to get the original password. Passwords are hashed using a codification with information loss, which makes impossible to reverse it

Comment: The exact algorithm of the hash is in the sources of Firebird, but I believe it is SHA-1, possibly combined with the original legacy hash that earlier versions used (a hash derived from DES).

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know TIBSecurityService is for Interbase 6 (see its entry on [Embarcadero's wiki](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/IBServices.TIBSecurityService)). I am not sure if that component still works for Firebird 2.1, since the original Firebird was a fork of that version.

Said this, you can **not** retrieve the original password. Passwords in Firebird are encrypted using a one-way encryption algorithm as stated in the [Firebird FAQ](http://www.firebirdfaq.org/faq55/). So if that was what you intended then it will not work.

What you could try to do is upgrade the security2.FDB database which holds the users  information. You can do that by making a backup of that database on the old Firebird server, and restore it on the new Firebird server. Check [this link](http://ibexpert.net/ibe/index.php?n=Doc.SecurityInFirebird2#DoingTheSecurity) for the steps to follow.

HTH

Answer (score 2):

In any decent application the passwords are not stored encrypted or in plain text.

They are stored by computing the hash of the password . Hasing should be not reversible thoug there are several weak hashing algorithms, I doubt the recovery is possible without a gross hack.

Answer (score 0):

**There is a way to access the db but without the old password**

I forgot also the password of old firebird database but according to this [documentation](http://www.firebirdfaq.org/faq55/)

> You can't. Passwords are encrypted using a one-way encryption
> algorithm and cannot be retrieved. When you log in, the server
> encrypts the password you enter and compares that hash with what is
> stored in security database.
>
> So, the only way is to reset the password, i.e. set a new one. If you
> still have SYSDBA password, it's easy as SYSDBA can alter password of
> any user. If not, you need to replace the security.fdb with a clean
> one (where you know the password).

All I have to do is to install fresh firebird set the "masterkey" or whatever password you want, restart, and I was able to access the fdb file using sysdba/masterkey.