# How to take database backup in firebird database in windows 2008 server?

Tags: database, firebird, credentials, administrator

Hello I am using firebird database for my application.

While noticing I found that the database is keep on increasing, even database contains very less amount the data file is very large.

The solution for this i found is taking backup and restoring, but problem is I don't know my sysdba password and also i tried using other users but it shows access denied.

Please suggest some fruitful solution.

Answer (score 2):

The Firebird SQL [default credentials](http://www.firebirdfaq.org/faq33/) for the administrator are:

- **username**: sysdba
- **password**: masterkey

When you log in, the server encrypts the password you enter and compares that hash with what is stored in security database (*native* authentication model, default on Windows). So if you forgot your password, you need to [replace the `security.fdb`/`security2.fdb` database with a clean one](http://www.firebirdfaq.org/faq55/).

The file `security2.fdb` (`security.fdb` for Firebird 1.5) is the [security database](http://www.ibexpert.net/ibe/index.php?n=Doc.SecurityInFirebird2), where Firebird keeps its user account details. It is located in your Firebird installation directory.
**It contains all the user passwords, not only the sysdba's password**, so keep a copy of the original file available at all times!

---

Backup/restore cycle isn't the only option. You could also try changing the garbage collection / sweep interval settings (e.g. see [Database Housekeeping And Garbage Collection](http://www.firebirdsql.org/manual/gfix-housekeeping.html))

Comment: thanks for your reply, I have one doubt does the existing other users will be cleared? If we replace the new security.fdb file.

Comment: I'm afraid so! You could save the encrypted password (of course you'll not be able to reverse the hash to get the original password) and try to restore them, but it isn't simple (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12953989/retrieve-firebird-users-passwords)